# How to model Requirements Using SPES and Harmony Method?

Tags: system, requirements, rhapsody, sysml

I am working on finding Requirement Modelling Methods. There are a lot of methods like SPES, Harmony, INCOSE OOSEM, JPL State Analysis etc.

I have gathered details regarding SPES Method but I want to compare this method with Harmony Method.

In SPES Method we have different Viewpoints like Requirement Viewpoint, Functional Viewpoint, Logical Viewpoint and Technical Viewpoint.

To model our Requirements we use Requirement View point and there are few model according to different artifacts. Models contains specific SysML / UML diagrams to explain the artifacts.

- Context model.
- Goal model.
- Scenario model.
- Structural Model (Data structures -SysMLBlock Diagram)
- Operational Model (SysML Activities Diagram)
- Behavioral Requirements Model
- Requirements Formalization

I know something about Harmony Method but vague description. 
Like we use Usecase diagrams for Requirement Modelling then we use activity Diagrams for description of relationship between requirements and then we use Sequence diagrams.

Can someone explain me about Harmony method? Which type of Model diagrams we use in Harmony Method?

How we model our requirements in Harmony Method?

Which Method is more useful SPES or Harmony and why?

Actually I will use the data based on this comparison to model our Requirements in IBM Rational Rhapsody tool.

Thanks a lot in Advance for cooperation and expert opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot editing this question. Is it possible for someone to please answer this questions. That will be great goodwill gesture.